# Four Threads in Function

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm

I have 4 threads that should enter to same function A.

1. I want to allow that only two can perform.
2. I want to wait for all the four and then perform function A.

How should I do it (in C++)?

Comment: In order to use multithreaded programming, you should at least read a tutorial, so that you have the basics down. Also, when asking here, you should at least show some effort instead of just dumping a homework question here.

Comment: This was an interview question that i asked.

Comment: 1. you should use a counting Semaphore... 2. what OS ?

Comment: When you say, "I want to wait for all the four and then perform function A."  Do you mean, you want to "wait for all 4 threads to finish and then in the main thread invoke the function"?  Or do you mean, "I want all 4 threads to reach the same point before one of them attempts to invoke the function" ?

Answer (score 0):

A condition variable in C++ should suffice here.

This should work for allowing only 2 threads from proceeding at once:

```
// globals
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
int active_runners = 0;

int FunctionA()
{
   // do work
}

void ThreadFunction()
{

    // enter lock and wait until we can grab one of the two runner slots
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m); // enter lock
        while (active_runners >= 2)  // evaluate the condition under a lock
        {
            cv.wait();  // release the lock and wait for a signal
        }
        active_runners++; // become one of the runners
    } // release lock

    FunctionA();

    // on return from FunctionA, notify everyone that there's one less runner
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m); // enter lock
        active_runners--;
        cv.notify(); // wake up anyone blocked on "wait"
    } // release lock
}
```

Comment: You can do a similar pattern for synchronizing all 4 threads.  Use a "waiting" variable, another mutex/condition_variable, and `waiting < 4` as the condition.